# Building Huffman encoding tree from ordered list

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I am building a huffman encoding tree from an ordered linked list (sorted by frequency of letters) that begins with the lowest frequency. After creating the tree, I traversed it and it appears that the tree was implemented incorrectly. When I traversed the tree, some of the nodes from the ordered linked list appeared to have be left out. (I don't think it was because my traversal is wrong.) Here is my code for the tree:

```
//My class for the nodes in the ordered linked list that will be converted to a tree
class fList{
public:
  fList();
  int frequency;
  char letter;
  fList* next;
  fList* left;
  fList* right;
};

fList::fList(){
  frequency = 0;
  letter = NULL;
  next = NULL;
  left = NULL;
  right = NULL;
}
fList* head = NULL;

    .
    .
    .
    .
    .

//Create the huffman encoding tree from the linked list stored in head
while(head->next != NULL){
    fList *tree = new fList();
    fList *temp = new fList();
    fList *trail = new fList();

    /* Take the first two frequency numbers, add them, create a new node                             
     * with the total frequency number and have new node point to the first                          
     * two nodes (right child and left child) 
     */                                                       
    total = (head->frequency + head->next->frequency);
    tree->frequency = total;
    //Set a new head node
    tree->left = head;
    tree->right = head->next;
    head = head->next->next;
    tree->left->next = NULL;
    tree->right->next = NULL;

    //place tree node in its correct place in sorted list                                           
    temp = head;
    trail = temp;
    if(head->frequency >= tree->frequency){
      tree->next = head;
      head = tree;
    }

    else if(temp->next != NULL){
      while(temp != NULL){
        if(temp->frequency >= tree->frequency){
          tree->next = temp;
          trail->next = tree;
          break;
        }
        else{
          trail = temp;
          temp = temp->next;
        }
      }//while                 

    //insert at the end of list                                                                   
    if(temp == NULL){
      temp = tree->next;
      trail->next = tree;
    }
  }//else if !=NULL 

  else if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL) head = tree;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the piece of code you posted, in the line

```
else if(temp->next = NULL && head != NULL) head = tree;
```

you inadvertently truncate the tree by setting `temp->next = NULL` where you probably meant to ask whether `temp->next == NULL`. This may be why some of the entries (the ones linked to by `temp`) are left out from the final result.

Comment: I actually commented that part out in my code but when I copied it here, I forgot to take it out. So I don't have that in my actual code. (I updated my code here to reflect that.) Thank you though!